# How do I disable autocomplete on quotation marks in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Every time I type quotation marks they autocomplete, I want to disable this because I want to practice doing it by hand so I can learn coding better, does anybody know how to do this? I searched on the web and couldn't find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to disable "Editor: Auto Closing Quotes" (`editor.autoClosingQuotes`).

[image: Setting]

The default is `languageDefined`.  If you want it completely disabled, set it to `never`.

Or, add this to your settings.json file:

```json
{
  "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never"
}
```